# WINFORM arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am running an SQL Server query in a WINFORM to get data and fill a DataGridview.

I am searching for certain files extension.

I am using for examples `like '%exe'`and get the results, for this and every file type there is in the database for examples; jpg, apk, cab etc…

The problem that I am having is when I search for file extension **.dll** every time I get the error: ***“arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.”***

I can run the same query inside SQL Server management Studio and search for the **dll** extension and get the results successfully.

Adding details:

I am also have a counter and Joins.

I can't paste the actual code with the tables name, so I substituted the names of the tables and columns.

```
select 
 t.column1, t.column2, t.column3 ,COUNT([column4]) as [Total]
 FROM table1 j 
 join table2 f on f.column1 = j.column1 and j.column7 = 1 
 join table3 t on j.column3 = t.column6
 join table4 lc on t.column6 = lc.column6
 where j.column2 like '%dll' Group by t.column1, t.column2, t.column3 order by Total desc
```

As I mention before, the query runs ok in the WINFORM C# for every other file extension that I enter and search for with the exception of the DLL in the.

Thanks again.

Any ideas? 
Regards

Comment: Please provide your full SQL query

Comment: Can you check in SQL profiler what query is made actually? Maybe something different is sent to server. How do you prepare query (using parameters or direct command)? If direct try use parameters instead.

Comment: The solution was to change COUNT to COUNT_Big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank everyone that took the time to read this thread.

The solution was to change `COUNT` to `COUNT_Big`

Once I did this my query executed successfully searching for the dll file extension.

Regards,